# Faster way of searching array of sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, set

I have an array containing 100,000 sets. Each set contains natural numbers below 1,000,000. I have to find the number of ordered pairs {m, n}, where 0 < m < 1,000,000,  0 < n < 1,000,000 and m != n, which do not exist together in any of 100,000 sets. A naive method of searching through all the sets leads to 10^5 * (10^6 choose 2) number of searches.

For example I have 2 sets set1 = {1,2,4} set2 = {1,3}. All possible ordered pairs of numbers below 5 are {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4} and {3,4}. The ordered pairs of numbers below 5 which do not exist together in set 1 are {1,3},{2,3} and {3,4}. The ordered pairs below 5 missing in set 2 are {1,2},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4} and {3,4}. The ordered pairs which do not exist together in both the sets are {2,3} and {3,4}. So the count of number of ordered pairs missing is 2.

Can anybody point me to a clever way of organizing my data structure so that finding the number of missing pairs is faster? I apologize in advance if this question has been asked before.

Update:
Here is some information about the structure of my data set.
The number of elements in each set varies from 2 to 500,000. The median number of elements is around 10,000. The distribution peaks around 10,000 and tapers down in both direction. The union of the elements in the 100,000 sets is close to 1,000,000.

Comment: Can we see your current way in a [MCVE]? A sample input with the desired output would be helpful to understand your situation as well.

Comment: @FirstStep: He is asking for a better algorithm. There is no point in writing pseudocode for the bruteforce search

Comment: Is there a limit to how many elements are in each set? Where did you get this problem from? Is it from a programming competition? Do you have a reason to believe this can be solved efficiently?

Comment: When you say `m,n < 1000000,` what does that mean? Does it mean both numbers are `< 1000000`? Or is there some function applied to both numbers to arrive at one number?

Comment: @hugomg I am solving a real-world problem at work. I have no reason to believe that this can be solved more efficiently. But it just feels there should be some better way to deal with this. Number of elements in each of the set could be as high as 500,000.

Comment: @Galik Yes both numbers should be less than 1,000,000.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about your expected output? Especially about `{m, n}`. I'm under an impression that you're looking for two numbers that don't exist in any sets.

Comment: Do you need that actual combinations that are absent or just the count of missing combinations ?

Comment: @Leben Asa I am looking for number of combinations {m.n} which do not exist in any of sets. For example I have 2 sets set1 = {1,2} set2 = {1,3}. Number of possible combinations of numbers below 4 is {1,2}, {1,3} and {2,3}. The combination which does not exist either of the two sets is {2,3}. Hope I am clear now. So the count of number of combinations is 1

Comment: @David Thomas I just need the count of missing combinations

Comment: @Sandeep Is the dataset sparse? i.e. of the integers between 0 and 1,000,000, are a majority present or absent from the 100,000 sets?

Comment: Its maybe better to ask this on: http://cs.stackexchange.com since it's not really C++ related

Comment: @Superlokkus I am using C++ data structures. So any optimization using C++ data structure will be appreciated.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Unfortunately, the data set is not sparse

Comment: Do you consider the pairs ordered? Is {2,3} the same as {3,2}?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes I am considering only ordered pair. So {2,3} is same as {3,2}

Comment: Check your example. 2 and 3 are present yet you say (2,3) is missing??

Comment: @DavidThomas {2,3} is not present together in set 1 and neither in set 2. So that is why I am saying it is missing.

Comment: @DavidThomas: As I undrstand, OP look for pair which cannot be construct in any set, from first set {1,2,4}, we cannot do {1,3}, {2,3}, {3,4}. Second set only allow {1, 3}, so remaining pairs are {2,3}, {3,4}

Comment: I find too many ambiguities in the problem statement. If I have set1=(3,4,8) and set2=(7,1000), are we only considering the combinations of these 5 values or do the values between the lower and upper bound matter? In the op example why isn't (1,1) a possibility?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am sorry about the ambiguities. In your example let us consider all pairs equal to or below 1000 (note: my question considers all pairs below 1 million). Possible pairs from set 1 are {3,4}, {3,8} and {4,8}. Only possible pair from set 2 is {7,1000}. Total number of ordered pairs below 1000 is 1000*999/2. So the ordered pairs missing is (1000*999/2) - 4. Please let me know if I am not clear

Comment: @Sandeep I can't really think of any algorithm that would obtain 10^6 * 10^6 time; that's actually pretty good for a naive algorithm given this problem. The best I can think of is 10^5 * (10^6 choose 2). Could you elaborate on what your naive approach is?

Comment: @DavidThomas {1,1} is not a possibility because m cannot be equal to n

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin You are right. Naive approach is actually 10^5 * (10^6 choose 2). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: In generating combinations, do you begin with the value 1 or the lowest value found in all arrays?

Comment: @DavidThomas, please begin with value 1.

Comment: You say the number of elements in each set could be as high as 500,000. But would a size of say 100,000 elements or more be a rare occurrence, and typically a set would be much smaller, or would the typical size be large (10,000 - 500,000)?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer The number of elements varies from 2 to 500,000. The median number of elements is around 10,000. The distribution peaks around 10,000 and tapers down in both direction.

Comment: Okay, then creating the set of pairs with both members appearing together in one of the sets is most likely infeasible. How large is the union of the sets? Counting the pairs where at least one member doesn't belong to any of the sets is easy, and if the union is noticeably smaller than `{1,…,1000000}`, you'd gain a non-negligible factor.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good idea! Unfortunately, for my data set, the union is pretty close to 1,000,000.

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised. Then at the moment I can't think of anything better than a slightly improved brute force. Pick the largest set containing 1, call it S[1]. Form all pairs `{1,n}` with `n > 1` and `n` not belonging to S[1]. Go through the remaining sets containing 1, and remove all pairs `{1,n}` with `n` belonging to S[k]. Count what's left. Remove 1 from all sets. Pick the largest set containing 2, call it S[2]. Form all pairs `{2,n}` with `n > 2` and `n` not in S[2]. Go through the remaining sets containing 2 and remove the pairs `{2,n}` with `n` in S[k].

Comment: Count what's left and add it to the previous count. Remove 2 from all sets. Pick the largest set containing 3 … I guess you know how to continue. It's still going to stink, but hopefully it stinks less than the totally naive way. (Well, always searching for the largest set containing `m` is not necessary, it suffices to choose one of the largest. Sort the array by size, and re-sort it by size after every k rounds, where k should be not too small, perhaps 100 or 1000. Then pick the first in the array that contains `m` as the set S[m].)

Comment: You can exclude from standard processing numbers not a member of any of the given sets. When done with these, you can also weed out numbers that are in every set. Not sure whether there's an insight waiting about the (vast) rest…

Comment: `have to find the number of ordered pairs` vs. `way of organizing my data structure so that searching is faster`: is the second (searching to find _what_, btw?) the question to answer here, as the title suggests? Else, is it a feasible way to get the approximate or exact number of pairs?

Comment: @greybeard The goal is to find the number of ordered pairs missing. I just mentioned organizing the data structure as it may lead to the solution faster. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: My 2016 guesstimate for the runtime of [Asad Saeeduddin's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38936426/3789665) is _at least hours_: bordering intractable. This _might_ be an [X-Y-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): If there is another problem to solve and you think knowing that _number of pairs not in any of the sets given_ is (an essential) part of the solution, try sketching the root problem just the same. Consider posting it as a question of its own and cross-linking.

Comment: @DanielFischer: pity [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover) is NP-complete. Good thing there are approximations, starting with _big_ sets and a common element.

Answer (score 3):

First lets solve more simple task of counting number of elements not present in your sets. This task can be reworded in more simple form - instead of  100,000 sets you can think about 1 set which contains all your numbers. Then number of elements not present in this set is `x = 1000000 - len(set)`. Now you can use this number `x` to count number of combinations. With repetitions: `x * x`, without repetitions: `x * (x - 1)`. So bottom line of my answer is to put all your numbers in one big set and use it's length to find number of combinations using combinatorics.

**Update**

So above we have a way to find number of combinations where each element in combination is not in any of the sets. But question was to find number of combinations where each *combination* is not present in any of the sets.

Lets try to solve simpler problem first:

- your sets have all numbers in them, none missing
- each number is present exactly in one set, no duplicates across sets

How you would construct such combinations over such sets? You would simply pick two elements from different sets and resulting combination would not be in any of the sets. Number of such combinations could be counted using following code (it accepts sizes of the sets):

```
int count_combinations(vector<int>& buckets) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < buckets.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j=i+1; j < buckets.size(); ++j) {
      result += buckets[i] * buckets[j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now let's imagine that some numbers are missing. Then we can just add additional set with those missing numbers to our sets (as a separate set). But we also need to account that given there were `n` missing numbers there would be `n * (n-1)` combinations constructed using only these missing numbers. So following code will produce total number of combinations with account to missing numbers:

```
int missing_numbers = upper_bound - all_numbers.size() - 1;
int missing_combinations = missing_numbers * (missing_numbers - 1);

return missing_combinations + count_combinations(sets, missing_numbers);
```

Now lets imagine we have a duplicate across two sets: `{a, b, c}`, `{a, d}`.
What types of errors they will introduce? Following pairs: `{a, a}` - repetition, `{a, d}` - combination which is present in second set.
So how to treat such duplicates? We need to eliminate them completely from all sets. Even single instance of a duplicate will produce combination present in some set. Because we can just pick any element from the set where duplicate was removed and produce such combination (in my example - if we will keep `a` in first set, then pick `d` from the second to produce `{a, d}`, if we will keep `a` in second set, then pick `b` or `c` from the first to produce `{a, b}` and `{a, c}`). So duplicates shall be removed.

**Update**

However we can't simply remove all duplicates, consider this counterexample:
`{a, b}` `{a, c}` `{d}`. If we simply remove `a` we will acquire `{b}` `{c}` `{d}` and lost information about not-existing combination `{a, d}`. Consider another counterexample:
`{a, b}` `{a, b, c}` `{b, d}`. If we simply remove duplicates we will acquire `{c}` `{d}` and lost information about `{a, d}`.

Also we can't simply apply such logic to pairs of sets, a simple counter example for numbers < 3: `{1, 2}` `{1}` `{2}`. Here number of missing combinations is 0, but we will incorrectly count in `{1, 2}` if we will apply duplicates removal to pair of sets. Bottom line is that I can't come up with good technique which will help to correctly handle duplicate elements across sets.

Comment: I don't think that answers OP's problem: with `{1, 2, 3}` (with `4` as maximum instead of `1'000'000`, missing pairs are `{1, 4}`, `{2, 4}`, `{3, 4}` for a total of `3`, you don't find that number as I understand.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin: I exposed the 3 missing pairs, so result is not 1.

Comment: @Jarod42 Messed up earlier. You'd do an *intersection* of all sets, not a union. So your combined set would be `{1}` only, since this is the only member shared amongst all sets.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think I misunderstood the OP's question. I was assuming the combinations could be selected across sets, but from the sample problem edited in it looks like this isn't the case. If this *was* the case, this answer would work. The total number of 2 combinations from a set of numbers between 1 and 4 is 6. Given the union set {1, 2, 3}, we can say we have 3 distinct combinations available across all sets (3C2 = 3). This leaves 3 missing combinations, as you suggest in your comment.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Nice bottom line - consider putting it at the beginning of the post. Down-voting not because I don't appreciate your effort - I consider documenting unsuccessful approaches valuable - but to give promising ones a chance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for combinations *across* sets, there is a way to meaningfully condense your dataset, as shown in [frenzykryger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38934747/1726343). However, from your examples, what you're looking for is the number of combinations available *within* each set, meaning each set contains irreducible information. Additionally, you can't use combinatorics to simply obtain the number of combinations from each set either; you ultimately want to deduplicate combinations across all sets, so the actual combinations matter.

Knowing all this, it is difficult to think of any major breakthroughs you could make. Lets say you have `i` sets and a maximum of `k` items in each set. The naive approach would be:

- If your sets are typically dense (i.e. contain most of the numbers between 1 and 1,000,000), replace them with the complement of the set instead
- Create a set of 2 tuples (use a set structure that ensures insertion is idempotent)
- For each set O(i):

  - Evaluate all combinations and insert into set of combinations: O(k choose 2)

The worst case complexity for this isn't great, but assuming you have scenarios where a set either contains most of the numbers between 0 and 1,000,000, or almost none of them, you should see a big improvement in performance.

Another approach would be to go ahead and use combinatorics to count the number of combinations from each set, then use some efficient approach to find the number of duplicate combinations among sets. I'm not aware of such an approach, but it is possible it exists.

Comment: (In a comment, 10^4 is presented as the median cardinality of those 10^6 sets. If there wasn't much variance, there'd still be on the order of 10^14 insertions. Say you can do 10^8 per second and core (optimistic), and afford 10 cores: 10^5seconds. Representing a set of at most 5*10^11 elements is quite a stretch for 2016 main memory systems, but well within solid state storage sizes (if not everyone's budget), and access need not be "random".)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do, depending on memory requirements, is take advantage of the ordering of Set, and iterate over the values smartly.  Something like the code below (untested). You'll iterate over all of your sets, and then for each of your sets you'll iterate over their values.  For each of these values, you'll check all of the values in the set after them.  Our complexity is reduced to the number of sets times the square of their sizes.  You can use a variety of methods to keep track of your found/unfound count, but using a set should be fine, since insertion is simply `O(log(n))` where n is no more than 499999500000.  In theory using a map of sets (mapping based on the first value) could be slightly faster, but in either case the cost is minimal.

```
long long numMissing(const std::array<std::set<int>, 100000>& sets){
    std::set<pair<int, int> > found;
    for (const auto& s : sets){
        for (const auto& m : s){
            const auto &n = m;
            for (n++; n != s.cend(); n++){
                found.emplace(m, n);
            }
        }
    }
    return 499999500000 - found.size();
}
```

Comment: `take advantage of the ordering of Set` - how (is the code presented doing this)? How does this differ from Asad Saeeduddin's suggestion to `Create a set of 2 tuples … Evaluate all combinations and insert into set [to deduplicate]`? (I'd argue insertion as expected O(1) …)

Comment: It isn't that different from Asad's suggestion; I just wanted to demonstrate that the big O analysis overstates the cost.  I didn't read Asad's the way I read it now, and don't feel this contributes much more than showing how to iterate over the sets in order (which could be useful I guess).  If I'm honest my initial answer tried to be too fancy and I thought was faster than it was, but the current iteration has upvotes so I won't delete.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can build [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)(s) over your sets.

Before checking against all sets you can quickly lookup at your bloom filter and since it will never produce false negatives you can safely use your pair as its not present in your sets.

Answer (score 1):

Physically storing each possible pair would take too much memory. We have 100k sets and an average set has 10k numbers = 50M pairs = 400MB with `int32` (and `set<pair<int, int>>` needs much more than 8 bytes per element).

My suggestion is based on two ideas:

- don't store, only count the missing pairs
- use interval set for compact storage and fast set operations (like [boost interval set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html))

The algorithm is still quadratic on the number of elements in the sets but needs much less space.

Algorithm:

- Create the `union_set` of the individual sets.
- We also need a data structure, let's call it `sets_for_number` to answer this question: which sets contain a particular number? For the simplest case this could be `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>` (vector stores set indices 0..99999)
- Also create the inverse sets for each set. Using interval sets this takes only `10k * 2 * sizeof(int)` space per set on average.

  ```
  dynamic_bitset<> union_set = ...; //union of individual sets (can be vector<bool>)
  vector<interval_set<int>> inverse_sets = ...; // numbers 1..999999 not contained in each set
  int64_t missing_count = 0;

  for(int n = 1; n < 1000000; ++n)
      // count the missing pairs whose first element is n
      if (union_set.count(n) == 0) {
          // all pairs are missing
          missing_count += (999999 - n);
      } else {
          // check which second elements are not present
          interval_set<int> missing_second_elements = interval_set<int>(n+1, 1000000);
          // iterate over all sets containing n
          for(int set_idx: sets_for_number.find(n)) {
             // operator&= is in-place intersection
             missing_second_elements &= inverse_sets[set_idx];
          }
          // counting the number of pairs (n, m) where m is a number
          // that is not present in any of the sets containing n
          for(auto interval: missing_second_elements)
              missing_count += interval.size()
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, have a set of all numbers and remove each of the number when you insert to your array of set. This will have a O(n) space complexity.

Of course if you don't want to have high spec complexity, maybe you can have a range vector. For each element in the vector, you have a pair of numbers which are the start/end of a range.